# PUT or PATCH, which is faster and why?

Tags: api, rest, methods, patch, put

As per information available on web, PATCH is faster than PUT in REST API. But, if we're not checking before updating anything then PUT should be faster.

**Definations:**

- The PATCH method is the correct choice if you're updating an existing resource.
- PUT should only be used if you're replacing a resource in its entirety.

Specifically, the PUT method is described as follows in [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> Several applications extending the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)
> require a feature to do partial resource modification. The existing
> HTTP PUT method only allows a complete replacement of a document. This
> proposal adds a new HTTP method, PATCH, to modify an existing HTTP
> resource.

Answer (score 1):

> which is faster and why?

I don't think either of them is necessarily faster - [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) (defined by RFC 7231) and [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) (defined by RFC 5789) are constraints on message semantics, not on implementation performance.

In cases where the representation of the resource is much larger than the HTTP headers, and the representation of the patch document is much smaller than the representation of the resource, the network latency might be a lot better than the additional time required to execute the patching.

Which is to say, I think you have to measure the latency profiles in your context, rather than expecting some universal ordering to apply.

> Do you think that say 12 fields without foreign keys (I'm not sure if foreign keys even matter) constitute as a small object so that it'd make more sense to use PUT or would PATCH be fine (and what if 5 of those fields are foreign keys -- in case it matters)?

Foreign keys really shouldn't enter into the discussion at all; they are an implementation detail of the server; the client should be completely unaware of them.

Comment: Like when submitting data, we are not sure how many fields we have updated then using PATCH can be costly in terms of PATCH.

Comment: @SiddharthJain Do you think that say 12 fields without foreign keys (I'm not sure if foreign keys even matter) constitute as a small object so that it'd make more sense to use PUT or would PATCH be fine (and what if 5 of those fields are foreign keys -- in case it matters)?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Thanks. About whether to choose PUT vs PATCH, I know you mentioned that it depends on testing the specific endpoint. But at how little fields would you generally say that PUT is fine because replacing such a small amount of fields (as a whole) is not problematic (3 fields, 10 fields, 20 fields)?

Comment: PUT/PATCH are from a remote authoring domain - I'm "saving changes I made to a web page".  We should prefer to use PUT when saving changes, because components in the HTTP application can do intelligent things with messages that are constrained to be "idempotent".  If the representation is large (compared to the HTTP headers, and the patch document that describes our changes is small (compared to the representation) then PATCH might make more sense (the tradeoff here is fewer network packets vs weaker retry semantics).